# Add all numbers that are in a list

Tags: python, list, recursion

So if I have a list, let's say: `[1,2,'hello']` and I want to add all the numbers in a list, (strings should be ignored). I want it to return the number 3 (1+2). And the function must be recursive.

This is what I have come up with:

```
import numbers
def isnumber(x):
  return isinstance(x, numbers.Number)

def sum_first(list):
    if not list:
        return 0
    elif isnumber(list[-1]):                        
        return list[-1] + sum_first(list[:-1])   


list=eval(input("Enter a list: "))
print(sum_first(list))
```

This only works if the last element in the list is a number. Let's assume it's a string, how could I change it?

Comment: Obviously I meant 3, sorry, changed it now.

Comment: Remember that python's lists are `arraylists`. Doing a slice is **O(n)**. I'd try to avoid a recursion form that slices lists at every iteration.

Comment: what about strings that are numbers? such as '4'

Comment: @aruisdante: when learning about recursion, such performance considerations are well out of scope, I'd say. If performance is an issue, there are much better ways to sum a list..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only handling two cases:

1. the list is empty
2. the last element is a number

Your example list doesn't fit *either* case, so you end up returning `None`.

Add a *third* branch:

```
def sum_first(lst):
    if not lst:
        return 0
    elif isnumber(lst[-1]):
        return lst[-1] + sum_first(lst[:-1])
    else:
        return sum_first(lst[:-1])
```

Now you handle the case where the last element is not a number; you handle it by ignoring it; recursing with the list without that one element.

I renamed your `list` variable to `lst` to avoid masking the built-in type.

Comment: Thanks! But in the else statement, how come we are not using "isnumber" again?

Comment: @raspberrysupreme: `else` is used if both other tests did not match. So if `not lst` is false *and* `isnumber(lst[-1])` is false, *then* `else` is used.

Comment: @raspberrysupreme: in other words, we don't have to use `isnumber()` at all here; we already know that that test failed.

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` can be seen as a form of recursive function. If you don't intend to write your own recursive function then may be you could do this

```
import operator as op


def silent_int(v):
    try:
        return int(v)
    except ValueError:
        return 0


xs = [1, 2, 'hello', '4']

print reduce(op.add, map(silent_int, xs))
```

Obviously the correct way of counting numbers should be using `sum` but with the recursion restriction you could use reduce or build your own trampoline!

Comment: You'd use `sum()`, not `reduce()`, for the straightforward implementation. But the OP is trying to learn recursion, not how to sum numbers efficiently.

Comment: @MartijnPieters already mentioned that ``sum`` should be the way forward if the recursion was not needed.

Comment: But `reduce()` is not recursive; it feeds results from one call to the next, but that is not the same thing, really. It is a different concept altogether.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is a HOF to do recursion without you having to call your function. I can see this view can be subjective though.